# Error 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, c

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04. Everything works PHP, PHPMYADMIN, manual login to MySQL etc.

I have written a C application that uses MySQL. Now, when I start this application I receive the above error. I tried to prevent that from happening by linking the original file into the /tmp/ folder (ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock), however, after a while I start getting this error again - because my link has been removed, which is frustating.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL libraries are compiled with a default of `/tmp/mysql.sock`. The server is started up with `/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock` and your `$HOME/.my.cnf` does not reflect this value in the `[client]` section.

If this is run without a valid $HOME you may need to use [mysql_options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-options.html) with MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE.

Comment: Thanks Mel, I do indeed run it without a valid $HOME variable. I tried mysql_options(conn, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE, "/etc/mysql/my.cnf") in my C application right after the mysql_init but nothing seems to happen. Any thoughts?

Comment: @frank That file needs to contain a [client] section where `socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock`.

Comment: It does have a client section with the port and the socket specified?!

Comment: I also tried to specify the socket directly in mysql_real_connect

Comment: It does not seem to read the file because the error is still the same pointing to /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: Check if your app has permission to get to the socket. But it would help if you show your code. Hard coded socket in mysql_real_connect should override any option values.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking the file in other location than /tmp/ and use it from there

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of his code connecting to the wrong socket.